# How to prevent add/remove udev loop

Tags: usb, udev

i'd like to use a midi keyboard (eagletone tinykey) on a udoo (sort of raspberry board).
When plugging the device, it won't setup correctly.

Doing a

```
udevadm monitor
```

shows a sort of add/remove loop:

```
KERNEL[1174.215632] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[1174.218337] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1174.222021] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2 (sound)
KERNEL[1174.222417] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2/midiC2D0 (sound)
KERNEL[1174.222708] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2/midi2 (sound)
KERNEL[1174.223329] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2/dmmidi2 (sound)
KERNEL[1174.223700] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2/controlC2 (sound)
KERNEL[1174.224050] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[1174.225644] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2/midi2 (sound)
KERNEL[1174.226290] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2/dmmidi2 (sound)
KERNEL[1174.226739] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2/midiC2D0 (sound)
KERNEL[1174.227161] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2/controlC2 (sound)
KERNEL[1174.227637] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2 (sound)
KERNEL[1174.227889] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1174.228311] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[1174.229425] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1174.232087] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1174.238406] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1174.242659] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1174.243523] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2 (sound)
UDEV  [1174.244195] remove   /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1174.253150] add      /devices/soc0/soc.0/2100000.aips-bus/2184200.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/sound/card2/midi2 (sound)
...
```

On a desktop system ubuntu, i observed the same problem a few months ago, and this is now fixed (probably by an update), the device is well set up in less than 2 seconds.

```
lsusb
```

extract on my destop:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0218:0401 Hangzhou Worlde
```

Any suggestion to fix this kind of problem?
I wonder if the answer is in modifying some udev rule, or more in the kernel, or even in some initialisation script?